# How to use ansible template module with variable receiving value from hostvars?

Tags: ansible, ansible-inventory, ansible-template

In templates/config.py:

```
{% if env_value == 'Dev' %}
  {% set x = {{hostvars['ces_dev']['ansible_host']}} %}
{% else %}
  {% set x = {{hostvars['ces_demo']['ansible_host']}} %}
{% endif %} 

API_CONFIG = {
    'api_email_url': 'http://{{x}}:8080/api/users/mail',
}
```

In host inventory:

```
ces_dev    ansible_ssh_private_key=<path>   ansible_host=a.b.c.d

ces_demo   ansible_ssh_private_key=<path>   ansible_host=x.y.z.w
```

Expected output, if condition is met:

```
API_CONFIG = {
        'api_email_url': 'http://a.b.c.d:8080/api/users/mail',
    }
```

I am getting an error: `"msg": "AnsibleError: template error while templating string: expected token 'colon', got '}'`

How to resolve this and get the desired output?

Comment: Please provide a full [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) with a minimal template, playbook and data to reproduce your problem. The error is most probably in your playbook or included vars (or a part of your template we don't see).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I cracked the expected output myself, with several try-hit-error method. The solution is:

```
API_CONFIG = {
    {% if env_value == 'Dev' %}
    'api_email_url': 'http://{{hostvars['ces_dev']['ansible_host']}}:8080/api/users/mail',
    'api_token_url': 'http://{{hostvars['ces_dev']['ansible_host']}}:8080/api/app/',
    {% else %}
    'api_email_url': 'http://{{hostvars['ces_demo']['ansible_host']}}:8080/api/users/mail',
    'api_token_url': 'http://{{hostvars['ces_demo']['ansible_host']}}:8080/api/app/',
    {% endif %} 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The variables are expanded by default. For example

```
{% if env_value == 'Dev' %}
  {% set x = hostvars.ces_dev.ansible_host %}
{% else %}
  {% set x = hostvars.ces_demo.ansible_host %}
{% endif %}
API_CONFIG = {
    'api_email_url': 'http://{{x}}:8080/api/users/mail',
}
```

Comment: Thanks! Though I cracked it in a different way, this too works.